# How can I make an imitation of a button control with a picture box, that behaves exactly like a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, controls, picturebox

Buttons do that: if the user preses and holds he left mouse button over a button control and moves the cursor out of the control, the button control changes it's appearance back to default, and if the mouse button is still being held, and the cursor enters a button control, the control changes it's appearance to it's pressed version. I'm trying to imitate a button using a PictureBox, but when the mouse leaves the PictureBox before the left mouse button is released, the PictureBox's picture doesn't change until the mouse button is released.

I'm trying to do this because the button control can't look the way I want to.

How can I make an imitation of a button control with a picture box, that behaves exactly like a button?

Comment: And just to be clear, this has to be done in Winforms, correct? You can't use WPF?

Comment: You should consider customizing the painting of a button rather than use a picturebox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, the control sets the Capture property to true so it will keep receiving mouse messages while the button is held down when you move the mouse outside of the control rectangle.

You could turn it off when you see it moving out:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var box = (PictureBox)sender;
        if (!box.DisplayRectangle.Contains(e.Location)) box.Capture = false;
    }
```

Comment: The PictureBox also has 3 images for the cases: when the PctureBox is free, when the cursor is over the PictureBox but the left mouse button (LMB) is not down and when the LMB is down and the cursor is inside the PictureBox. This method works only when the mouse leaves the control, while the LMB is down. But when the cursor enters the PictureBox while the LMB is down, the picture of the control doesn't change to the image for the third case. This solution works only when the mouse leaves, but it doesn't work when the mouse enters the control...

Comment: Well, sure, other controls may capture the mouse as well.  Whichever one you clicked on.  It isn't any different for a regular button control.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DragLeave event as opposed to the MouseLeave event.